# Add admin levels to corresponding lat/long

Tags: qgis, latitude-longitude, administrative-boundaries

I am fairly new in using GIS, I have a dataset with lat/long references, corresponding to points throughout the world. I would like to add the corresponding admin1,2 and 3 levels. I've been trying through QGIS to do a spatial join but haven't found an open source world GIS layer with admin1,2 and 3.

any ideas would be deeply appreciated. Sorry in advance for my little knowledge.

Comment: You can download it from here: https://gadm.org/download_world.html

Comment: Most lat/long locations over land will be in **all** of admin1, admin2 and admin3 polygons. Most countries are divided into all three administrative regions. (Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question?)